# Data model, many-to-many and one-to-many relation

Tags: data-modeling

So we are developing a KPI and Initiative management system for a client.
In the image you can see the data model we've built based on the client's needs.
Basically this is the hierarchy of our data model: Strategic Objective linked to one entity > KPI > Initiative

Recently we've discovered from the customer that the strategic objective and KPI could be shared between more than one entity, but in the end for each entity there is a different Initiative.

I don't know how to reflect this in the data model. But I came up with three possible solutions:

1- Breaking down the Strategic Objective and Entity relation from one-to-many to many-to-many. And also the Strategic Objective and KPI relation to many-to-many, but this does not solve my problem. As in the end I want to model that for example SO1 is shared between entity1 and entity2, so is the KPI but not the Initiative.

2- EntityOwner table, that basically maps the Strategic Objective or KPI or Initiative to the entity directly.

3- Instead of mapping the entity to the strategic objective, we map it to the Initiative.

[The Datamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb4jg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not remove the relation between the KPI and Initiative and instead create one between Entity and Initiative?

Such model resembles the fact that KPIs seem to be in the domain of business performance while initiatives lie more on the side of programmes / projects office. In other words a business creates initiatives to satisfy strategic objectives not KPIs. KPIs are for visibility.

I would also query whether Strategic Objectives should have direct relationship with Entities, or whether there should be relationship SO -
- INITIATIVE -- ENTITY.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We decided to break down all the relationship to many to many and create an owner table, that basically maps SO, KPI and Initiative to entity directly. So far the client did not mention a direct relation between SO and Initiative, their business says there must be a KPI in between that measures performance.

Comment: After I last wrote my comment, we were nearing a milestone in the project and the client sent an email to specifically ask that we map Initiatives directly to the strategic objectives, he also said something along the lines of what sir. you said which was like "Initiatives satisfy SO not KPI".